# Spark sql return empty dataframe when read hive managed table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 2.4 and Hive 3.1.0 in HDP 3.1 , I am trying to read managed table from hive using spark sql, but it returns an empty dataframe, while it could read an external table easily.
How can i read the managed table from hive by spark sql?

Note: The hive maanged table is not empty when reading it usig the hive client.

1- I tried to  format the table by ORC an parquet and it failed in both.

2- I failed  to read it using HWC.

3- I failed to read it when using JDBC.

```
os.environ["HADOOP_USER_NAME"] = 'hdfs'

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName('NHIC')\
    .config('spark.sql.warehouse.dir', 'hdfs://192.168.1.65:50070/user/hive/warehouse')\
    .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://192.168.1.66:9083")\
    .enableHiveSupport()\
    .getOrCreate()

HiveTableName ='nhic_poc.nhic_data_sample_formatted'
data = spark.sql('select * from '+HiveTableName)
```

The expected is to return the dataframe with Data but Actually the dataframe is empty.

Comment: Can you first try simple `spark.sql("describe formatted nhic_poc.nhic_data_sample_formatted").show(1000,False)` and see if it works?

Comment: It returns the described formatted table.

Comment: Can you try changing the NameNode port in `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` from 50070 (http) to 8020 (rpc), or remove this config completely (`hive.metastore.uris` should be sufficient to use external metastore). Next, I'd verify the `spark.sql.hive.metastore.version` against your actual Hive metastore.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if your spark environment is over-configured?

Try to run the code with environment's default configurations, by removing these lines from your code:

`os.environ["HADOOP_USER_NAME"] = 'hdfs'`

`.config('spark.sql.warehouse.dir', 'hdfs://192.168.1.65:50070/user/hive/warehouse')`

`.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://192.168.1.66:9083")`

Comment: It's just saw the default database , and did not saw any tables.